# Selected references without hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links

When using the `hyperref` package, is it possible to tell LaTeX not to create a link for some references?

In my case the page number is displayed in the footer in

```
\fancyhf[FC]{\thepage\ of \pageref{pg:end}}
```

which is what I want. Unfortunately every single page in the document then has a link to the final page, which is a bit silly.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the starred command: `\pageref*{pg:end}` to suppress the link for any *ref command.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine for the \pageref command, but not so for the \eqref. I would like to disable the hyperlinking for some of those as well, as it is a bit over the top linking to the same page the user is already on...

Comment: @user7091: If you are have to (i would just let all of them link), then you could wrap up your own command, `\newcommand{\eqrefb}[1]{(\ref*{#1})}`

Comment: Yes, I ended up going for that option. Links to the same page are a bit too much. Now that I started implementing footnotes I see that I have the same problem there. How would I turn the hyperlinking of those off?

Comment: Works also with \ref*{}