# \cite without hyperlink (Citation in captions)

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

I want cite a reference (by using `\citet`, `\citeauthor` or `\citeyear`.) inside a `\caption{}`.  Something like this:

```
\caption{Characteristics assessed in \citet{perell_fall_2001}}
```

I'm using the `natbib` package as well as `hyperref`.  The thing is that I don't want the reference to have the hyperlink to its bibliography entry (because it looks awful in the list of tables at the beginning of the document).

Is there any way to achive this?  I've found one question very close to what I'm looking for:

[Selected references without hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/selected-references-without-hyperlink)

But it is for `\ref`, not for `\cite`...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\small
\centering
    \caption{Characteristics assessed in \citet{perell_fall_2001}}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
\bfseries Patient Characteristic & Number of studies\\
\firsthline\\
Mental status or cognitive impairment & 5 \\
        \lasthline\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:PerrellAssesment}
\end{table}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

Where `refs.bib` is:

```
@article{perell_fall_2001,
    title = {Fall Risk Assessment Measures An Analytic Review},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {1079-5006, 1758-{535X}},
    url = {http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/56/12/M761},
    doi = {10.1093/gerona/56.12.M761},
    number = {12},
    journal = {The Journals of Gerontology Series A: Biological Sciences and Medical Sciences},
    author = {Perell, Karen L. and Nelson, Audrey and Goldman, Ronald L. and Luther, Stephen L. and Prieto-Lewis, Nicole and Rubenstein, Laurence Z.},
}
```

Comment: @MarcoDaniel it didn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can temporally disable `hyperref` by using the environment `NoHyper`. The environment is fragile so you have to use `\protect`:

```
 \caption{Characteristics assessed in {\protect\NoHyper\citet{perell_fall_2001}\protect\endNoHyper}}
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{perell_fall_2001,
    title = {Fall Risk Assessment Measures An Analytic Review},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {1079-5006, 1758-{535X}},
    url = {http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/56/12/M761},
    doi = {10.1093/gerona/56.12.M761},
    number = {12},
    journal = {The Journals of Gerontology Series A: Biological Sciences and Medical Sciences},
    author = {Perell, Karen L. and Nelson, Audrey and Goldman, Ronald L. and Luther, Stephen L. and Prieto-Lewis, Nicole and Rubenstein, Laurence Z.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}[!ht]

    \caption{Characteristics assessed in {\protect\NoHyper\citet{perell_fall_2001}\protect\endNoHyper}}
    \label{tab:PerrellAssesment}
\end{table}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

Maybe you want to use the optional argument of caption:

```
 \caption[Characteristics assessed in {\protect\NoHyper\citet{perell_fall_2001}\protect\endNoHyper}]{Characteristics assessed in \citet{perell_fall_2001}}
```

Next hint: Use `\label` immediately after `\caption`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! :).