# Force second pass in lyx for total page numbering

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

I'm trying to put the total page number in the footer of my Lyx-doxument  (a la https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235/89786) by putting in the preamble the following

```
\fancyhf{}               % Clear fancy header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}  % Page number in center footer
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy   % Plain page style = fancy page style
\makeatother
```

Somehow lyx only seems to do one pass of the page numbers and I get a footer (on the 5:th page) reading: "Page 5 of ??".

Any ideas?

I can add a label at the last page called `LastPage`, but this creates a hyperlink label as

[image]

which is really ugly.

Comment: Document > Settings... > PDF Properties > Hyperlinks > No frames around the links

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/selected-references-without-hyperlink ?

Comment: Judging by the fact that the reference works when you manually added the label, I would guess that you did not include `\usepackage{lastpage}`. That package will automatically define the `LastPage` label. Without a label, it doesn't matter how many times the document is generated, the reference will always just show `??`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out one crucial thing from the code in the https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235/89786:

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
```

This package will automatically create a label called `LastPage` on the last page. If you don't have that label, it doesn't matter how many times you'd run `pdflatex`, the cross-reference would of course never work.

As for the look of the cross-references, that can be changed in Document --> Settings, as Fran mentioned in a comment:

[image: document settings in LyX]